# Angular 4 Displaying Data From Rest API

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, express

I'm having problems displaying data from my local express.js REST API, which is structured like this:

```
 people: [{ surname: 'testsurname', name: 'testname', email: 
 'testmail@gmail.com', status: 1, activity: 'Office' }
```

I have a people service where I get the data, it looks like this:

```
export interface People {
  surname: String;
  name: String;
  email: String;
  status: Boolean;
  activity: String;
}

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {

private _peopleURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/people";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
console.log('init PS')
}

getPeople(): Observable<People[]> {
return this.http
    .get(this._peopleURL)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        return <People[]>response.json();
    })
  }


}
```

This is my PeopleComponent.ts code

```
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {
  _peopleArray: People[];

  constructor(private ps: PeopleService)
   { }

   getPeople(): void {
    this.ps.getPeople()
        .subscribe(
            resultArray => this._peopleArray = resultArray,
            error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
        )
}


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPeople();
  }
```

Now I'm trying to display the data (i.e. the name) in my 'People' component.html like so:

```
<div> {{people.name}} </div>
```

When I start my app I get an error saying

```
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]
```

Can anyone explain to me what I missed and what I need to be doing in order to display the data?

Comment: have you tried printing people[0].name ? as it is an array

Comment: @HrishikeshKale Yes, but then I'm getting "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: If using HttpClient i would suggest:

 return this.http.get<People[]>(this._peopleURL , { observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'});

this way you don't need to .map()

Comment: _peopleArray.name will work

Comment: @HrishikeshKale Unfortunately not, still getting undefined

Comment: opps sorry it's an array use {{_peopleArray[0].name}} it will work

Comment: @HrishikeshKale this one worked but I'm getting an error saying "TypeError: response.json is not a function"

Comment: try to console this value 
.map((response: Response) => {
console.log(response.json());
        return <People[]>response.json();
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You response is json `array` .try following code snippet.

```
<div *ngFor ="let p of people">
      <div> {{p.name}} </div>
   </div>
```

**Update**

Change your service method as shown below.The default value that returns new HttpClient is Object. It automatically calls `response.json()` internally.

```
getPeople(): Observable<People[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<People[]>(this._peopleURL);

  }
```

Check out following working demo

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8c2kip?embed=1&file=app/people.service.ts)

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm getting an error saying "Error :: TypeError: response.json is not a function"... any headers to what I did wrong?

Comment: Try to import `'rxjs/add/operator/map'` That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me plenty!

Answer (score 0):

You should do this to print your JSON structure "*Array of object*"

```
   <div *ngFor ="let person of _peopleArray">
      <div> {{person.name}} </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: There's no need for safe navigation operator here :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have "people" field in your component, you're setting it to "_peopleArray".

But even if you change it to

```
<div> {{_peopleArray.name}} </div>
```

it still won't work since _peopleArray is, well, an array.

You can iterate over array objects with *ngFor or access only first or nth element of the array like so

```
<div> {{_peopleArray[0].name}} </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm getting an error saying "Error :: TypeError: response.json is not a function"... any headers to what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you console.log your response before trying to access it's data with .json()?

Comment: You shouldn't "return" anything from your Observable. Change your service method to this:      " return this.http
    .get(this._peopleURL)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        <People[]>response.json();
    })
  } "